# How to customise Firebase in-app messages in iOS app

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

Any details to customize the In-App messaging? Can I show a customized popup with two buttons and the header title and subtitle for the popup using Firebase In-app messaging in ios?

Any sample or details on how to customize this?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/customize-messages?platform=ios#create_your_own_message_display_library

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
class MyInAppMessagingDelegate: NSObject, InAppMessagingDelegate {
func messageClicked(_ inAppMessage: InAppMessagingDisplayMessage, campaignInfo: InAppMessagingCampaignInfo?) {
    // Check if the message is of type InAppMessagingModalDisplay
    guard let modalDisplay = inAppMessage.displayInfo as? InAppMessagingModalDisplay else {
        return
    }
    
    // Check the button ID to perform specific actions
    if inAppMessage.triggerAction.actionButton?.buttonId == "updateButton" {
        // Handle Update button click
        // Add your custom logic here
    } else if inAppMessage.triggerAction.actionButton?.buttonId == "cancelButton" {
        // Handle Cancel button click
        // Add your custom logic here
    }
}
```

}

you can try this for two button (update and cancel)

Answer (score -1):

To customize the display of In-App Messages in your app, you need to implement the FIRInAppMessagingDisplayDelegate protocol. This allows you to provide a custom display for your In-App Messages.

Here's an example of how you can customize the In-App Message display:

```
import FirebaseInAppMessaging

class CustomInAppMessagingDisplayDelegate: NSObject, FIRInAppMessagingDisplayDelegate {
    
    func messageClicked(_ inAppMessage: FIRInAppMessagingDisplayMessage, with action: FIRInAppMessagingAction) {
        // Handle the click action for the In-App message
    }
    
    func messageDismissed(_ inAppMessage: FIRInAppMessagingDisplayMessage, dismissType: FIRInAppMessagingDismissType) {
        // Handle the dismiss action for the In-App message
    }
    
    func messageWillDisplay(_ inAppMessage: FIRInAppMessagingDisplayMessage) {
        // Customize the display of the In-App message
        
        // Access the message components
        let title = inAppMessage.messageContent.title.text
        let subtitle = inAppMessage.messageContent.body.text
        let actionButton1 = inAppMessage.messageContent.actionButton?[0]
        let actionButton2 = inAppMessage.messageContent.actionButton?[1]
        
        // Create a custom popup with the message components
        // Display the popup with the provided title, subtitle, and buttons
    }
    
    func impressionDetected(for inAppMessage: FIRInAppMessagingDisplayMessage) {
        // Track impression events for the In-App message
    }
}

// Register the custom display delegate
FIRInAppMessaging.inAppMessaging().delegate = CustomInAppMessagingDisplayDelegate()
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: Can I able to set two buttons? One is update and Cancel in the popup?

Comment: Sure, you can do it in messageClicked function. I 'll add code in other answer. You can try this

Comment: This looks like another copy-paste from ChatGPT